# Do we have a Father of all living things, if yes what’s Adam’s role and the meaning of this scripture

Tags: genesis, creation, genealogy, earth, family

Genesis 3:20 KJV
[20] And Adam called his wife's name Eve; because she was the mother of all living.

Comment: _Furthermore we have had fathers of our flesh which corrected us, and we gave them reverence: shall we not much rather be in subjection unto **the Father of spirits**, and live?_  Hebrews 12:9. (Good question. Up-voted +1.)

Comment: Actually, Eve was not the mother of all living. We need only look to Adam, who had no "mother." Eve wasn't a mother until Cain. Thus, Eve is the mother of *most* of the human race, while Adam is its human father - with the exception of Eve. That is, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: At risk of sounding pedantic, everyone takes it as understood that Eve was only to become mother to future humans. Verse 20 says "because she was the mother of all living" but not of any animals, obviously - only humans. Further, before Adam named the woman 'Eve', God had foretold "her seed" (verse 15) so Adam named her in faith that she would become mother to all future humans.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we do have a Father of all living things but that one is not Adam! This then requires an explanation as to why Adam names the woman God had given him ‘Eve’ (*Chavah* in Hebrew). Notice that he did not name her until after the pair had disobeyed God and received God’s decree? He had earlier named all the animals, for God directed him to do that, but that was before the woman was formed from his rib. Yet Adam did not give the woman a name – until now. What prompted that?

God had just spoken to the serpent saying,

> “And enmity I do put between thee and the woman, and between thy seed
> and her seed: he doth bruise thee – the head, and thou dost bruise him
> – the heel.” Then, to the woman God says, “Multiplying I multiply thy
> sorrow and thy conception, in sorrow dost thou bear children, and
> toward thy husband [is] thy desire, and he doth rule over thee,”

When God finishes speaking to Adam, he then names the woman Eve; “for she hath been mother of all living” (I quote from *Young’s Literal Translation of the Bible*.) It surely does not need to be said that this is all about her being mother to humanity. Eve was never mother to, or nurturer of, animal or plant life. But I say it anyway, for clarity, because God had already given the green light to procreate (Genesis 1:28).

The past tense is interesting in 3:20. Adam was clearly speaking in faith, trusting in God’s assurance that she would bear children, from which all humanity would result. He would be the literal father of all the literal babies that Eve would give birth to, but there’s a deeper, spiritual meaning here.

Hebrews 12:4-11 brings in God as Father of those who have striven against sin; He disciplines, scourges, even, all those whom He calls ‘sons’. The writer contrasts God’s fatherly disciplining of his children with that meted out by our physical, earthly fathers. We respect “fathers of our flesh” (note the plural in vs. 9 – not one father, as in Adam). How much more should we “be subject to the Father of the spirits, and live?”  This is where we need to go back to Eden, bearing that in mind.

Adam and the woman attempted the impossible – to rise to a higher level, to be as God himself, but failed, only succeeding in discovering a lack in their humanity. They lacked something. They felt exposed and felt shame. God had never drawn attention to them being unclothed but after judging that first, failed humanity, he provided covering (through sacrifice), to prepare them for the chill winds and briars outside of Eden. Inside Eden there was no failure, not until the first Adam chose to cast his lot in with his wife instead of abiding by God’s prohibitive command. That is why the Bible puts the responsibility for sin entering the world, and death through sin, on Adam’s shoulders (Romans 5:12). Adam gave rise to the first, failed, humanity. But God already had the last Adam, already viewed as “the Lamb slain from the foundation of the world” (Revelation 13:8), the first hint of which came in Genesis 3:15.

But note that the woman was taken out of the man before he fell. Before Adam transgressed, woman was taken out of him. From the ‘Mother of all living’ would come a seed. Not of man, but of woman. Not a progeny of a failed humanity – another humanity altogether – a new creation. Nor would it be a new thing out of the old. This would come by redemption, not by attempts at self-righteousness (note how the woman blamed the serpent, and the man blamed the woman, which was actually blaming God who had given him her?) The seed of the woman said “Ye must be born again”, a birth of water and of Spirit, from above – being born of God, which makes him our Father, for spiritual begetting comes from God the Father – the Father of spirits, as in Hebrews 12.

This brings me full circle so I will stop, resisting going back to stop at all the myriad other details that could (and should) be brought in along the way to give a fuller answer to your important question.

Comment: Mmm, you said ... “*Adam and the woman attempted the impossible – [....] to be as God himself, but failed,*”. - But, someone else said .... GEN 3:22 Then the Lord God said, “Behold, the man has become like one of Us.”

Comment: @Dave _See YLT_ : 'The man _**was**_ as one of us.' Now he has partaken of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil. _So he is no longer one of us and must leave Eden._ If the man is now 'as us' and we banish him for being as us, then the Serpent is correct and his lie is true : that God does not desire the man to be 'as one of us'.

Comment: @Nigel J I note the view you take from Young’s tense of ‘echad’, but the interpretation of this verse needs a wider foundation than just that. I have much respect for Young, but, nevertheless, his angle is not unanimous. A literal translation does *not* always help. The difference here is brought about by this newly acquired ‘knowledge’. And, the question is, what difference does ‘knowledge of good of evil’ make? And, why was God against this, yet, provided the option?

Comment: @Nigel J ... and, as for the serpent ‘lying’, another [huge?] problem many have is with the definition of ‘a lie’. A lie (biblically) is *not* something that’s ‘false’. (That’s only in ‘western thinking’). Biblically, a ‘lie’ is something that is not Truth. BUT - nevertheless, it may be ‘right’. The 10 spies gave a report, and everything they said was right, was a fact, but nevertheless it was *not* truth. Similarly, every thing the serpent said was ‘right’ (correct). But because it wasn’t what God said, means it was not truth. This is exactly what deception is!

Comment: @Dave  If you wish to explore the points you raise, you could ask your own questions, or go to the “Chat” section of the site. The “Comments” are not intended to start any debates but to give ideas for the answerer you are responding to to improve their answer. This site is to provide room for different answers, then the person asking the question can choose a best one, if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

The name **חַוָּה Chavah** is a derivative of the Hebrew word **חַיָּה chayah** meaning “living” in singular feminine form. In the Chabad [article](https://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/335943/jewish/Chavah-Mother-of-All-Life.htm) “Mother of All Life” - Sara Esther Crispe states :

> Chavah embodies both the essence of life itself and the creative ability to grant that life to others. The idea of “mother of all life” expresses not only the ability to physically give birth, but also to create, nourish, and enhance all facets of life. This is the ability of a mother - to take something from the state of potential, develop it, and bring it to actualization through her creative abilities.

[To honor God, The-Man הָֽאָדָם Ha-Adam named אִשְׁתּ֖וֹ his-wife: חַוָּה Chavah whose image was made in the likeness of God & whose creative abilities were like יְהֹוָ֨ה The Father of all Life].

Genesis / **Bereishit 3:20**

> “And The-Man named his wife **Chavah**, because she was the mother of all life.” ( וַיִּקְרָ֧א הָֽאָדָ֛ם שֵׁ֥ם אִשְׁתּ֖וֹ **חַוָּה** כִּ֛י הִ֥וא הָֽיְתָ֖ה אֵ֥ם כָּל־חָֽי )

Comment: No, it's not a derivative of chayah. Chavvah is a Canaanite/Phoenician word that was adopted in Hebrew and means exactly "living" and this is a Canaanite pun, because the same word is a homophone to "rib" as per the discussion in Genesis, but *not* in Hebrew. There's a nice article on this in TDOT.

Answer (score 0):

**Gen 3**

14 And the **Lord God said unto the serpent**, Because **thou hast done this**, thou art cursed above all cattle,

15 And **I will put enmity between thee** **and the woman**, and **between thy seed** **and her seed;**

20 And Adam called his **wife's name Eve**; because she was the **mother of all living**.

**john 8 44**

44 Ye are of your **father the devil**, and the **lusts of your father** ye will do. He was a **murderer from the beginning**

**Statement**

The **Lord God and the Son of God**, gave all details on this Subject

**Eve was the Mother** of all living

The **Serpent was Satan**

**Adam wasn't the Father** of all the Living

This was **the Original Sin**

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: Scripture interprets Scripture, especially from The Lord God and the Son God. Satan is the only source of Evil, Sin took place by an act of Satan through Eve

Comment: @David take a tour and read the meta topics, this site is not like forums and doesn't expect such kind of answers.

Comment: Michael. When difficult scripture is commented on, it is usually a matter of opinion, using scripture too, make the Pieces fit, this is amplified, by New Age Bible that agree with the popular version of the Topic. The bible is a perfect jig saw puzzle, that requires an in depth study or the Context of the Subject. Any departure from the correct context, will destroy God's Word, that is the reason,  one Bible, so many Churches, with some many answers

Comment: Michael. Eve was the mother of all living, her first child was Cain,